# Cakephp login page ask for table users but I only have a user table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I'm following the cake tutorial for [Cakephp 3.0](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/_downloads/en/CakePHPCookbook.pdf)

I'm in the part where I want to do the login page. I have a database called `medical_wear` and a table `user`.

When I enter my email and my password on the login page I get the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'medical_wear.users' doesn't exist Please try correcting the issue for
>   the following table aliases: Users

I don't understand I don't have a Users table and I don't use a Users table in the code.

I have searched in many topics and in the documentation and I found nothing.

I have this in src/Controller/AppController.php

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ] 
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'User',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
    // Autorise l'action display pour que notre controller de pages // continue de fonctionner.
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
```

And in src/Controller/UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
        $user = $this->Auth->identify(); 
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Votre username ou mot de passe est incorrect.');
    }
}
```

In src/Template/Users/login.ctp

```
<h1>Connexion</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email') ?> 
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?> 
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?> 
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cakephp follow naming conventions

Database table and field naming convention

1. Table name must be in lowercase & plural. If there are more than one
   word in the table name then words should be separated by underscore.

   ```
   Example : users, consultant_services, etc.
   ```
2. Field-Name should also be in lowercase and if more than one word
   then separated by underscore.

   ```
   Example : id, consultant_service_name
   ```
3. ForeignKey name should be singular and tablename_id

   ```
   Example : users_id or consultant_services_id
   ```

Model naming Convention

1. Model file names are upper camel case, more than one word should be
   separated by underscore.

   ```
   Example : User.php or Consultant_service.php
   ```
2. Model class name are singular, usually this should be the database
   table name but in singular format.

   ```
   Example : User or ConsultantService
   ```

So your code should be

```
class UserTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('user');
    }
}
```

For more information [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful !

Comment: Glad to know it help.

Answer (score 0):

[CakePHP's naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) require table names to be plural. So you should have a `users` table in your `medical_wear` database and a `UsersTable` class in your app.

It is best to avoid going against Cake's naming conventions as it will create more problems than it is generally worth, but if you *must* have a singular `user` table you need to define this in your model.

```
class UserTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('user');
    }
}
```

The only real reason for having to break from the conventions is if you are needing to develop an app that uses an existing database that cannot be modified. If you are starting from scratch stick to the [conventions described in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) as it will simplify things immensely.