# How to create model in cake php 3+ version and load in controller

Tags: php, model, cakephp-model

I am creating the controller UsersController.php. after that i am creating the model User.php . when i am trying to load the model and run test functon, i have been seen the error :-

**Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:
User**

Please help me .

Thanks
Neeraj Mahajan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp login page ask for table users but I only have a user table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597237/cakephp-login-page-ask-for-table-users-but-i-only-have-a-user-table)